# Show that the units of a finite field form a cyclic group.

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, finite-fields

I have shown that for a finite commutative group, there is an element $x$ such that the order of every other element divindes the order of $x$. I was thinking how I could apply this to prove that the units of a finite field form a cyclic group.

Comment: What have you tried? Presumably there’s a finite group and a field to use ….

Comment: Yes, I did. Is the group the group of Units? But how can order help in this case?

Comment: Can you figure out what that maximum order must be? You obviously have to use the field somewhere! Start by giving the maximum order a name?

Comment: @TedShifrin well,it must be 1, right?

Comment: It cannot possibly be $1$. The group has more than the identity element.